# Implementing SSE using jersey not working after setting async supported to true

Tags: javascript, html, jersey, server-sent-events

I am trying to implement SSE using jersey in server side. I have multiple issues here : 
My server code is as follows :

```
@GET
@Path("message")
@Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
public EventOutput getMessage() {

    final EventOutput output = new EventOutput();
    try {
        output.write(new OutboundEvent.Builder().name("custom-message").data(String.class, "mymessage").build());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return output;
```

Initially, I was able to see the data coming every second using the browser network debugger. But each time the server sends an event, the server logs said something like :

> WARNING: Attempt to put servlet request into asynchronous mode has
>   failed. Please check your servlet configuration - all Servlet
>   instances and Servlet f ilters involved in the request processing must
>   explicitly declare support for asynchronous request processing.
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: !asyncSupported

So to fix this I added a async-supported tag into my web.xml. Now my web.xml looks like :

```
 <display-name>ssetest</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ssetest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>package.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ssetest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

. After this change, I am getting only a single event from the server . The events are not getting generated every second. Anything I missed in my configuration or code?

I am using the latest  jersey version. Server is jetty 9.

```
A snippet from my build.gradle : 
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.22'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-sse:2.22'
```

2 . I am unable to read sse events from My client code. My client code is as follows :

```
  if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
     var source = new EventSource("url");
     source.onmessage = function(event) {
     document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
};
```

The onMessage block is never executed. Anything wrong in my client code?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where's your web.xml

Comment: Added the web.xml file too